# Setting up Artifactory in Visual Studio 2022 fails with 403

Tags: c#, artifactory, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to set up JFrog artifactory in Visual studio 2022.
I usually login in JFrog via SAML SSO, but not getting this option in visual studio.
In visual studio, I'm not getting any option in that popup box to login via SAML SSO.
How do I Add my credentials, or is it possible or do i have to create a JFrog account.?

I am expecting to get access to my artifactory in visual studio.

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: Review this article: https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-how-to-configure-artifactory-as-symbol-server-and-integrate-with-visual-studio/building-and-publishing-the-symbol-nuget-packages-using-azure-devops-server-ci/cd-tool 2) If your organization purchased a JFrog license, consider opening a support call to ask about "SSO/Authorization" options with JFrog and MSVS.  FYI, Microsoft products tend to use OAuth2 more than SAML...but definitely support *BOTH*.  Please post back what you find!

Answer (score 0):

See the following documentation:
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-platform-administration-documentation/using-api-key-with-saml-users
API key can replace password but it will be deprecated soon.

You should be able to generate an access token (Or an admin should be able to create one for you) to replace user and password basic authentication and it can be used in Visual Studio configuration as well